# A pip subprocess error when I create an environment for one project in its root folder

Tags: python, numpy, pip, conda, environment

Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as WSL2 on Win10, I need to create an environment to install Devito on my system. So, in a root folder of this project I do:

```
(base) quant@NB-W-I-NIKONENKO:~/devito$ conda env create -f environment-dev.yml
```

and get this:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Installing pip dependencies: \ Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/home/quant/anaconda3/envs/devito/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/home/quant/devito/condaenv.r9s6c4x4.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in /home/quant/anaconda3/envs/devito/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r /home/quant/devito/requirements.txt (line 1)) (21.2.4)

Pip subprocess error:
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f27c959d970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f27c959d5b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f27c959df10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f27c95c5100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f27c95c52b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f27c8f2bc10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f27c8f2be20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f27c8f32040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f27c8f321c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f27c8f32370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/numpy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy>1.16 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy>1.16

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

The next installation commands should be:

```
source activate devito
```

which works, and the next:

```
pip install -e .
```

which shows the following:

```
Obtaining file:///home/quant/devito
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in /home/quant/anaconda3/envs/devito/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from devito==4.6.2+60.g9b765d0d6) (21.2.4)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa7509e1040>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa750a4d9d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa750a4d880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa750a4d190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa750a4dca0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/numpy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy>1.16 (from devito) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy>1.16
```

So, I can not install the package correctly and implement the final command:

```
conda update - all –yes
```

I noticed that base Python version is 3.7.6 and after the source activation python version is 3.9.7 (I am not sure if it helps but I really struggled with this problem).

Here is the link for installation instructions for the Devito
https://medium.com/@soulfoodpst/install-devito-on-windows-a-tool-for-automatic-programming-3def3949e5c8

Comment: Looks like a network issue to me. Do `pip install` commands work outside of this env? Do they work under windows? Are you behind a firewall (like in an institution or workplace) and might need to configure a proxy?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Yes, I think it works. I tried `pip install sklearn`, it says several times that the `Requirement already satisfied` and then `Successfully installed sklearn-0.0`. I am doing this from my home Wi-Fi and work laptop, I am not sure about any firewall. But if you can explain how to check this with proxy easily (if it is needed), I would be grateful.
 `pip install` works under windows in Anaconda terminal but I could not manage to install the required package via the `docker compose` method because of the `No module found ` error. So, this way with WSL2 should work but fails.